# Multiple Vue.set() not updating object/DOM

Tags: javascript, object, vue.js, vuejs2, settimeout

I'm learning VueJs and I'm trying to figure out what's the best solution for my problem.
The problem is that if I call `this.$set()` multiple times, only the last call will be registered.

I have tried using `setTimeout` (like in old angular1 days), but it still doesn't work.
Then I tried with `Vue.$nextTick()` which should rerender the DOM, but it seems that the data is not added fast enough in the object.

Check demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tbutcaru/pbwr3m3s/).
Press on every button multiple times and you'll see that the first log is skipped in the most of the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `Date.now()` is not correct.
it happens so fast, that the timestamp sometimes not changing between the 2 `this.$set` operations, so you override the value in `logs` object.

see the logs of `Date.now()` when i click the first button

```
 1509287060410 // first result of Date.now.
 1509287060412 // Second Result of Date.now - this time, it's different from the first attempt, so 2 different entries will be created.
 1509287061243 // another click on the button - timestamp has changed obviosuly.
 1509287061243 // Javascript did the second Set so far, that time timestamp didn't even changed yet. thus, it overrides the value of the second entry
```

so this log, the result of 4 `this.$set` operations, created this `logs` object:

```
{
    1509287060410:"I was clicked!"
    1509287060412:"I was clicked again!"
    1509287061243:"I was clicked again!"
}
```

The last `1509287061243` property was overrriden.

You have to **ensure** that the key of `this.$set` (second argument of the function) is different every time you call it.

See my new code suggestion:

```
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Multiple Vue.set() not updating object/DOM',
      logs: {},
      index: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    log: function(data) {
      console.log(Date.now())
      this.index += 1
      this.$set(this.logs, this.index, data)
    },
```

Comment: Wow, I have never ever thought about the fact that I might override the key! Doing this inside a framework, really makes you think just about it and pushing away the basics. I was only thinking that this is the same thing I was facing in the Angular world.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the logs type to `Array`. This way you won't miss any log due to key override. For example,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      logs: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    log(data) {
      this.logs.push({
        time: Date.now(),
        text: data
      })
    },
    logClick() {
      this.log('I was clicked!')
      this.log('I was clicked again!')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="logClick">Log click :)</button>
  <ul v-if="logs">
    <li v-for="(log, i) in logs" :key="i" v-text="log.text"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: I know about this, but I wanted to know why it doesn't work with object.